# Combining .html() qualities with .text()

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am making a site that displays html markup examples, much like stackoverflow.com does. With `.text()` I can display the markup as text, and with `.html()` I can format the text. I want to add a `<br />` with `.text()` as follows:

```
$("#affected_text").text("<p>line one</p><br /><p>line two</p>");
```

and it should display as:

`<p>line 1</p>` //note the line break
`<p>line 2</p>`

Comment: I have tried using `\n` but that only inserts one space

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\n` and insert the text into `<pre>` tag, [example](http://jsbin.com/odonoy/1/edit).

You could also add `white-space: pre;` to your output box if you don't want to use  tag.

Comment: Thanks man, do you know a link from which I can view a list of terms like `\n`? eg. `\n` corresponds to `<br />`, `\b` corresponds to `<strong></strong>`, etc.

Comment: No worries. I think it's only white-space related (\n - new line, \t - tab)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$("#affected_text").html("&lt;p>line one&lt;/p><br />&lt;p>line two&lt;/p>");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t9unn/

Answer (score 0):

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/Uu7s5/2/

```
$('p').text("<p>line one</p>\n<p>line two</p>");
```

**Html:**

```
<pre><p> </p></pre>
```